# Mouse copy in LibreOffice working every second time

Tags: libreoffice, copy

HP-EliteBook-Folio-9470m, Ubuntu 19.10, LibreOffice Version: 6.3.4.2
Build ID: 1:6.3.4-0ubuntu0.19.10.1.

Mouse copy works every second time. Example: copy 1, paste 1, copy 2, paste 1,copy 3, paste 3, copy 4, paste 3, etc.

Problem with external mouse, touch pad and icons on the tool bar. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> works properly.

Mouse copy from browser to terminal: OK; from terminal to terminal: OK, from Office to terminal: same problem.

Comment: I have the same version here and I can confirm that **the same problem exists here too**. Also, sometimes nothing is "Paste"d as if the Clipboard being empty. Clearly the problem is with the Copy function and not the Paste function.

Comment: This problem *persists* in **version 6.3.5.2** too.