# Ctrl-C not working on first try in LibreOffice, web browsers

Tags: libreoffice, clipboard, copy-and-paste

This behavior has been confirmed over a period of several days and multiple reboots.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> do not work the first time issued, in LibreOffice or web browsers (Vivaldi, Opera, Chromium, Firefox). Switching to another app, coming back the original, and re-issuing the keyboard shortcut seems to reliably *actually* put the selected region into the clipboard.

Anyone know why this is happening, and/or if there is a fix?

Comment: I can confirm that it doesn't work in Libreoffice on 19.10. Sometimes, simply doing Ctrl-C twice in a row works.

Comment: Refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic where you'll notice only supported releases of Ubuntu and flavors are on-topic for this site. For 20.04 questions you'll need to use a development support site such as IRC (#ubuntu+1) or Ubuntu Forums, or wait until after release for this site (expected release date for Ubuntu 20.04 is April 23rd, 2020 when your question will be on-topic here).  Problems should be reported as bugs.

Comment: It's not only on 20.04, but sometimes happens also on 19.10 that I use.

Comment: Might as well remove the 20.04 tag.

Comment: Might be related to: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1208305/mouse-copy-in-libreoffice-working-every-second-time

Comment: As Ubuntu 20.04 hasn't been completely locked up (freeze wise), I'd recommend reporting it as bugs on 20.04 as currently SRUs won't be required to fix (unless adding new features, unlikely with bug fixes) so it'll allow it to be far more easily fixed longer-term.

Comment: thanks for the edit, @FedonKadifeli   And yes, to echo others, I started noticing this behavior on 19.10 (server).